# Get second object from json after countdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm using a [countdown script](http://www.gieson.com/Library/projects/utilities/countdown/) from mike giesson to create some sort of Day Deal function. The script has an `onComplete` function. The product data comes from a json file.

I build the product html with a getJson query. This is functioning good. The only thing I try to achieve is that when the onComplete function is fired the second object in the json file is called. After that the third etc...

**Is this even possible?** I have other options, like building for example 5 products and hide and show when done. I thought it would be nicer to build it this way :)

So what I have done:

jQuery

```
 function getDaydealProducts(){
      $.getJSON('url/page1.ajax', function(data){

        var productsHtml = [];
        $.each(data.products, function(index, product){
          var productHtml =
              '<div class="item">' +
              ... etc .... + '</div>';

          productsHtml.push(productHtml);
        });
        productsHtml = productsHtml.join('');
        $('.clock').html(productsHtml);
      });   
      )

    var myCountdown1 = new Countdown({
      onComplete : countdownComplete
    });

    function countdownComplete(){
     getDaydealProducts(); //get second product. 
    }
```

So I tried to build a function that grabs the products, then start the counter. After that a new json call needs to be done with the second object.

Is that possible? And can somebody give me some directions?

thx

Comment: Damn you with your non-conventional indentation and mismatched brackets! I had an answer to this, but now I think I'd totally misread the question. Please fix it.

Comment: @DavidKnipe: I'm sorry what do you mean?

Comment: About 2/3 of the way down, you've got a `)` on a line by itself. I now think it was supposed to be a `}` (end of the definition of `getDaydealProducts`). I had previously thought that it wasn't meant to be there, and that the extra `}` should have been at the end (so the definition of `getDaydealProducts` would contain the definitions of `myCountdown1` and `countdownComplete`). Since the latter are not inside the function definition, they should be indented no more than `function getDaydealProducts(){`. (Indentation doesn't really matter, of course, it just makes it clearer.)